# « Un espèce de » ou « une espèce de » ?

Tags: genre, locutions

On entend ou lit souvent des phrases comme :

> Jean est un espèce de vilain.

(avec souvent un autre mot de 3 lettres à la place de « vilain »). Or, le mot *espèce* est du genre féminin et on dit plutôt dans d'autres cas :

> La baleine est une espèce de cétacé.

Ne devrait-on donc pas dire :

> Jean est **une** espèce de vilain.

?

Par curiosité, connait-on la raison de ce genre de mutation ? Est-ce que ça porte un nom ?

---

We regularly hear or read sentences like:

> Jean est un espèce de vilain.

(often with another 3-letter-word in place of *vilain*).  However, the word *espèce* is feminine and in other cases we rather say:

> La baleine est une espèce de cétacé.

Therefore, shouldn't we say:

> Jean est **une** espèce de vilain.

?

Out of curiosity, what's the reason for this kind of mutation?  Does it have a name?

Comment: Oui, ça porte un nom. Ça s'appelle une [syllepse selon le genre](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllepse#Syllepse_selon_le_genre).

Comment: On peut même vraisemblablement aller plus loin que la question initiale... c'est ce qu'a fait l'auteur de la chanson de Patti Layne, *Un espèce de canadienne*... ;-) Ceci n'étant pas un appel à controverse bien entendu, juste un *edge case* s'il fallait en citer un ^^

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Espèce** est féminin. L'emploi familier de « un espèce de » où l'accord se fait avec le nom masculin qui suit est considéré comme fautif quoique fréquent à l'oral.

[La règle](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/%C2%AB-un-espece-de-sorcier-%C2%BB-%C2%AB-une-espece-de-sorcier-%C2%BB).

[Ce qu'en dit l'Association des Journalistes](http://www.journalistes-patrimoine.org/index-fr.php?page=ajp_article&id_article=1341).

[C'est aussi la position de l'Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/le-dictionnaire-la-9e-edition/exemples-de-remarques-normatives).

Le dictionnaire historique de la langue française atteste l'emploi de cette tournure dès 1705.

---

**Espèce** is feminine.  The casual usage of *un espèce de* where the gender agreement is with the masculine name that follows is considered incorrect, though frequent in spoken language.

[The rule](http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/%C2%AB-un-espece-de-sorcier-%C2%BB-%C2%AB-une-espece-de-sorcier-%C2%BB).

[What the Association of Journalists says about it](http://www.journalistes-patrimoine.org/index-fr.php?page=ajp_article&id_article=1341).

[Which the norm as dictated by l'Académie française as well](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/le-dictionnaire-la-9e-edition/exemples-de-remarques-normatives).

The historical dictionary of the French language attests the usage of this turn of phrase from the year 1705.

Answer (score 8):

*Le Bon Usage* (§ 431 a.) est un peu plus nuancé que Laure ne le dit..

Essentiellement, l'accord du **verbe** dont le sujet est le groupe nominal *espèce de* + nom (ainsi que de certains compléments selon la syntaxe de la phrase) se fait généralement avec le complément du nom plutôt qu'avec *espèce*. Notons aussi qu'*espèce*, *genre*, *manière*, *sorte*, etc. sont **toujours singuliers** sauf dans *toutes sortes de*.

Quand à l'accord des **déterminants** de ce groupe nominal, Grevisse indique « Le caractère adjectival du syntagme *espèce de* est tel qu'*espèce* lui-même prend fréquemment le genre du nom complément. » Il qualifie cet accord d'usage oral qui pénètre à l'écrit, donnant des exemples qui remontent à Voltaire et Diderot.

Answer (score 6):

Excepté dans le langage parlé ou informel, *espèce* est censé être employé au féminin. Par contre, en lisant l'[article correspondant](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esp%C3%A8ce#Orthographe) sur Wikipédia, on se rend compte que l'orthographe de l'expression entière diffère selon le sens qu'il faut lui attribuer (biologique ou non) :

> En français usuel, on écrit « Le bonobo est une espèce de singe » (une sorte de singe) mais un biologiste écrira de préférence « Le bonobo est une espèce de primate**s** » (un groupe de primates).

---

Excepting spoken or informal language, *espèce* is supposed to be used with the feminine gender.  On the other hand, reading the [corresponding article](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esp%C3%A8ce#Orthographe) on Wikipedia, we should remember that the entire expression's orthography differs according to the sense being given to it (biological or not):

> In normal French, one writes “*Le bonobo est une espèce de singe*” (some sort of monkey / kinda a monkey) but a biologist would prefer to write “*Le bonobo est une espèce de primate**s***” (a species of primates).

Comment: À y repenser, l’absence de la marque du pluriel à *cétacé* m'avait choqué sans que j'aie pu dire pourquoi.

Comment: Subtil! Bien vu et bel extrait, merci!

Answer (score 5):

Il s'agit d'un usage du langage courant dans lequel un nom prend une valeur d'adjectif. « Un espèce de » n'est pas le seul exemple :

> Putain c'est trop con
>   ***Ce*** putain d'camion
>   Mais qu'est-ce qu'y foutait là
>
> dans *Putain de camion* de Renaud

Comment: Et si ta réponse nous plait pas, tu la remets dans ton Futal ? ;-) (eh ben elle me plait j'ai mis +1)